# AspNetCore v2.0 — Render razor-views in another project for integration tests

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-2.0, razorengine

I want to write integration test for my web-application. I used `Microsoft.AspNetCore.TestHost.TestServer` to communicate with controllers via url. But views cannot be rendered. In response I get error-message:

> One or more compilation references are missing. Ensure that your
>   project is referencing 'Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web' and the
>   'PreserveCompilationContext' property is not set to false.

In my .csproj I tried to change project-sdk on `Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web`, I tried to add `<PreserveCompilationContext>true</PreserveCompilationContext>`. Also I tried to rewrite the code as described in Microsoft-docs ([here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/testing/integration-testing) in [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/testing#integration-testing)).
But I still have the same error-message.

Steps to Reproduce:

- Create test-project "`WebApplication1.IntegrationTests`".
- Add reference on WebApplication-project.
- Add nuget-package "`Microsoft.AspNetCore.TestHost`"
- Send get-request to "/Home/Index" via `TestServer`.
- Read response with error-message.

```
using WebApplication1;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.TestHost; 
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace WebApplication1.IntegrationTests
{
    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            // Path to contentRoot folder. 
            var contentRootPath = @"..\..\..\..\WebApplication1";

            var builder = new WebHostBuilder()
                .UseStartup<Startup>()
                .UseEnvironment(EnvironmentName.Development)
                .UseContentRoot(contentRootPath);           

            var server = new TestServer(builder);
            var client = server.CreateClient();            

            var response = client.GetAsync("/Home/Index").Result;
            var responseString = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
        }
    }
}
```

Rendered `responseString` in browser:
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to test an ASP.NET Core 2.0 application recently, I have had to update the csproj file of the integration test project with the `<PreserveCompilationContext>true</PreserveCompilationContext>` property and with an additional target to copy the `.deps.json` file.

```
<!--
  Work around https://github.com/NuGet/Home/issues/4412. MVC uses DependencyContext.Load() which looks next to a .dll
  for a .deps.json. Information isn't available elsewhere. Need the .deps.json file for all web site applications.
-->
<Target Name="CopyDepsFiles" AfterTargets="Build" Condition="'$(TargetFramework)'!=''">
  <ItemGroup>
    <DepsFilePaths Include="$([System.IO.Path]::ChangeExtension('%(_ResolvedProjectReferencePaths.FullPath)', '.deps.json'))" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <Copy SourceFiles="%(DepsFilePaths.FullPath)" DestinationFolder="$(OutputPath)" Condition="Exists('%(DepsFilePaths.FullPath)')" />
</Target>
```

You can check the source code of the full integration test project [in github](https://github.com/DaniJG/BlogPlayground/tree/master/BlogPlayground.IntegrationTest). There might be additional differences, like I have used a full path with the `.UseContentRoot(path)` method.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using AspNetCore v2.0 you should instantiate your webhost in your program file like so

```
public static IWebHost BuildWebHost(string[] args) { 
     return WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args) //<-- See what this does 
            .UseStartup<Startup>()
            .Build();
    }
```

Then insure that your project has preservecompilationcontext set to true like you apparantly did. Also i'm assuming that you're targeting the .Net 4.6.x runtime.

Comment: Unfortunately, It didn't help me. With `WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder` I have same result. And yes - I definitely use AspNetCore v2.0.